# Angular5 - Compare Arrays and return matches

Tags: arrays, angular5

I need to compare two arrays and return the matches:

**Array1**

```
(13) ["0:EQSOLREENVIO", "1:EQPER", "2:EQCAN", "3:EQRECHKODOC", "4:EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC", "5:EQINDEV", "6:EQCAMBIODI,EQENV,EQFECHA,EQFIESTA,EQINCITRASP", "7:EQENT", "8:EQDEV", "9:EQRCH", "10:EQADMIPDV", "11:EQCRE,EQRETENER", "12:EQRECOOFI"]
0: "0:EQSOLREENVIO"
1: "1:EQPER"
2: "2:EQCAN"
3: "3:EQRECHKODOC"
4: "4:EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC"
5: "5:EQINDEV"
6: "6:EQCAMBIODI,EQENV,EQFECHA,EQFIESTA,EQINCITRASP"
7: "7:EQENT"
8: "8:EQDEV"
9: "9:EQRCH"
10: "10:EQADMIPDV"
11: "11:EQCRE,EQRETENER"
12: "12:EQRECOOFI"
length: 13
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**Array2**

```
(3) ["11", "0", "5"]
0: "11"
1: "0"
2: "5"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**What I have tried:**

```
    const orderStatusCodes = this.orderInProgressCmsModel.orderStatusCodes.split("/");
    const orderGroupsEditables = this.orderInProgressCmsModel.orderStatusLogEditables.split(",");
    let groupFound = '';
    const groupFound2 = [];

    orderGroupsEditables.forEach((element2) => {
      orderStatusCodes.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.indexOf(element2) >= 0){
          groupFound = element.split(":")[1];
          groupFound2.push(groupFound);
        }
      });
    });
```

**Result:**

```
(4) ["EQCRE,EQRETENER", "EQSOLREENVIO", "EQADMIPDV", "EQINDEV"]
0: "EQCRE,EQRETENER"
1: "EQSOLREENVIO"
2: "EQADMIPDV"
3: "EQINDEV"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

When the numbers match from each array I need the code returned. I have been able to do this with the code I show but I would like to know if theres an easier way like using filter or something similar?

Comment: Are you wanting to match both `"0:EQSOLREENVIO"` and `"10:EQADMIPDV"` for the `"0"` element in your `array2`?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel nope, each number needs to be an exact match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that depending on how big the arrays are, you might want to have a more performant algorithm. The solution presented in the question and the one supplied by @Mohammed Mortaga will loop through the second array for every element in the first array (in big O notation, that would be `O(n*m)`). This is doing a lot more work than is needed. You really only need to loop through each array a single time (in big O notation, that would be `O(n+m)`).

You can create a lookup table by looping through `array1` that you could then use to lookup if the id exists (and readily have access to the corresponding code):

```js
const regex = /^([^:]*):(.*)/;
const lookup = array1.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const [, id, code] = regex.exec(val);
  acc[id] = code;

  return acc;
}, {});
```

Once you have your lookup table it is constant time complexity to get the code that corresponds to each element in your `array2` (meaning for each item we don't need to search for a match, we can know in constant time if there is a match or not). Here you could use `reduce`:

```js
const codes = array2.reduce((acc, id) => {
  const code = lookup[id];

  if (code) {
    acc.push(code);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

or you could use a one-liner:

```js
const codes = array2.filter(id => lookup[id]).map(id => lookup[id]);
```

The one-liner would be slightly less performant because it is doing two looping operations, but that is relatively minor if the array is pretty small in length (and the big O notation would still be the same but the readability is increased).

Comment: I like the idea of a lookup table. +1

Comment: I like your approach but im having trouble understanding what this does: const [, id, code] = regex.exec(val); Why is there a comma before id and code?

Comment: @PLATANIUM That is new syntax in JavaScript. It is called destructuring. It can pluck values out of an array. The `id` and `code` values are the second and third item in the array. The first item can be skipped since we don't need it and hence there is no variable there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this using a single `filter` function like so:

```
const array1 = ["0:EQSOLREENVIO", "1:EQPER", "2:EQCAN", "3:EQRECHKODOC", "4:EQAUS,EQCDE,EQDDE,EQINACCE,EQVAC", "5:EQINDEV", "6:EQCAMBIODI,EQENV,EQFECHA,EQFIESTA,EQINCITRASP", "7:EQENT", "8:EQDEV", "9:EQRCH", "10:EQADMIPDV", "11:EQCRE,EQRETENER", "12:EQRECOOFI"];

const array2 = ["11", "0", "5"];

const result = array1.filter(e => array2.indexOf(e.match(/\d+/)[0]) > -1); // ["0:EQSOLREENVIO", "5:EQINDEV", "11:EQCRE,EQRETENER"]
```

In short, this code iterates over the first array extracting the digits and checks if they exist or not in the second array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain this part to me? e.match(/\d+/)

Comment: `e` is the current element your loop is operating on.
`.match` finds a subset of the string based on the given pattern.
`/\d+/` is the regex pattern we're using which simply says "give me the first match of one or more digit in `e`.

You should be careful though, if the arrays you're extracting data from aren't perfectly typical to the format in the example you gave us your app may crash.